# Problem hiding a div element with simple JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a very small project and I tried to make a `div`, gave it a `css style` and I can't hide it and I can't figure out why.

```js
 var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", open);
    var popup = document.getElementById("popup");

    function open() {
      popup.classList.toggle("hidden");
    }
```

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #popup {
        width: 15em;
        height: 20em;
        background-color: rgb(51, 50, 50);
        color: rgb(0, 159, 252);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 1em;
      }
      .labels {
        padding: 0.5em 0;
      }
      .inputs {
        background-color: white;
        color: rgb (51, 50, 50);
      }
      .bottom {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: flex-end;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #cancel {
        color: red;
        position: relative;
        bottom: -5em;
        left: 3em;
      }
      #confirm {
        position: relative;
        bottom: -5em;
        left: 2em;
        color: rgb(0, 159, 252);
      }
      .hidden {
        display: none;
      }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="OPEN" id="button" />
    <div id="popup" class="hidden">
      <h2>Add town</h2>
      <label for="name" class="labels"><span>Name</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="nameInput" class="inputs" />
      <label for="country" class="labels"><span>Country</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="country" id="countryInput" class="inputs" />
      <div class="bottom">
        <p id="cancel">Cancel</p>
        <p id="confirm">Confirm</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried using `inspect` in Chrome but I don't get any errors.

Comment: try moving 
          .hidden {
            display: none;
          } to the beginning of your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have has to do with CSS priority. The `display:none` is being replaced by the higher priority `display:flex` defined inside the `#popup`.

[image]

Therefore you should use :

`display:none !important;`

Comment: Learning is a process. You need to understand the reasons in order to understand the solution. This is where the "Cascading" comes from in CSS, means that css rules have different priorities based on certain aspects, which you need to understand in order to know when they will become more important than others, and will end up being responsible for the result.

Comment: It is possible to help me solve another issue ? This `popup div` is displayed behind a `leaflet map` that has a container. That map container has `position: absolute`. Tried using `z-index: 0 on map container` and `z-index: 1 on popup div` but it does nothing.

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) . A common way to use this would be to use position:relative on the parent element of the popup and then use position : absolute on the popup, and specify the z-index then on the popup . Please check https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ .

Answer (score 0):

You have `#popup{display: flex;}` which overwrites your `.class{display:none;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide your `div` because it has display `flex` provided by `id` selector. As `id` selector has priority over your `hidden` class. What you can do is combine your `hidden` class selector with id. Also here is good article about [Specificity](https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) in CSS.

```
#popup.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```